# How to update a value in a specif key of firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I update a value in an existing key in firebase database from android. In my case I want user to update the key **Votes**

[image]

```
                        final long z=0;
                        Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                        taskMap.put("Votes", z);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                .child("project_image").child(projectDate)
                                .child("Votes")
                                .updateChildren(taskMap);
```

I tried the above codes but instead it add another node

[image]

```
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
       .child("project_image")
       .child(formattedDate)
       .push().setValue(dataMap);
```

The above codes were used to insert data at the first time

How can I perform this task

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: noted sir,sorry 4 the inconvinience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the key also:

```
    final long z=0;
 Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
 taskMap.put("Votes", z);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("project_image")
.child(projectDate).child("-M3zLjPHM_ndBfBDLV9C")
.child("Votes")
.updateChildren(taskMap);
```

---

To get the key:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

reference.child("project_image").child(projectDate).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String key = datas.getKey();

   final long z=0;
   Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
 taskMap.put("Votes", z);
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("project_image")
.child(projectDate).child(key)
.child("Votes")
.updateChildren(taskMap);
    }
 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
 });
```

Comment: how will I get that particular key in android?

Comment: you can iterate and retrieve the key from the database using getKey and then update

Comment: still I get another new node.Note the key you suggested to getKey() it was generated automatically  when inserting the data at first time, check my edited codes.

Comment: if this `projectDate` is equal to `12:24:18 PM,3 APR 20` then it will work, if not then use a query `orderByChild("Title").equalTo("covid")` then u will get the key, and use a Log to check what `key` you are getting..